# Is there a better way to create an object from addition of 2 objects keys in Dart?

Tags: dart, merge, key, addition

I made a Stats class with only int properties. I want to create a method to add two Stats instances to create a new one. What I have done is the following :

```
class Stats {
    final int movement;
    final int strength;
    final int constitution;

    Stats(
            {this.movement,
            this.strength,
            this.constitution});

    Stats add(Stats other) {
        return Stats(
            movement: this.movement + other.movement,
            strength: this.strength + other.strength,
            constitution: this.constitution + other.constitution);
    }
}
```

Is there a clever way to make this by using mapping on key to key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Dart object properties are not something you can abstract over, at least not without using `dart:mirrors` (and then it really stops being *clever*).